# Linking to a DLL with a DEF file instead of a LIB file?

Tags: windows, linker, dynamic-linking, function

I have learned that you can:

- <strike>Convert a .DLL file into a **.DEF** file, which includes its exports</strike>
  (Edit: This doesn't work with many conventions)
- Convert a **.DEF** file into a .LIB file, which you can use to link to the DLL

Why can't (most) linkers link to a DLL given *only* a .DEF file, instead of a .LIB file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately, the answer here is 'because noone wanted it badly enough and it doesn't really help anything'.

The DEF file is an input file that creates an import lib for the DLL. And then, later, when the DLL is being consumed by another link, the importlib is itself an input. The importlib looks like something special on the outside, but when you look at the inside it's really just a slightly special lib with objects in it.

It totally would be possible to modify the linker to take a def file (or a DLL, for that matter) directly.

But the design centre of the linker is that it takes objects as inputs and outputs a PE executable. So taking a DEF or DLL as an input goes outside the design pattern.

Beyond that it'd be rather pointless - allowing the linker to take a DEF file or DLL as input would neither enable any important new scenarios, nor does leaving this feature out block anything. Converting a DEF file you have (even without the actual DLL) into a usable importlib is the work of a few moments (simply create fake empty function for each DEF entry and link that). So there's no reason to add the ability to link a DEF file directly.

Martyn

Comment: [Confirming your point, MinGW/GCC does support linking directly against the DLL.](http://sources.redhat.com/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/WIN32.html)

Answer (score 3):

In terms of MSVC, .lib files are always static libraries. They get linked in as a compilation unit along with all your compiled .c/.cpp files, so all of the library's code is included in your final executable.

Some .lib files, however, (in particular most of the Windows system ones) merely contain stubs which tell the OS to load the desired DLL at loadtime and then the stubs route function calls to the DLL. But, those stubs *are* statically linked into your executable. Your program will then use DLLs (and gain all the advantages and disadvantages thereof), but since the named DLL functions it requires are happily located in the .lib (and thus actually located in the executable itself), your code doesn't have to know it's using a DLL (specifically using declspec(dllimport)).

A .def file is merely used as a sort of "settings" or "configuration" file during the creation of a .dll to specify what functions the file should export. It cannot be linked to, as it doesn't really describe anything that the linker understands.

Answer (score 2):

You do not convert a dll to a DEF file. The DEF just indicates which dll functions will be accessible from the outside, exported.

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> > A DLL file has a layout very similar to an .exe file, with one
> >     important difference — a DLL file contains an exports table. The
> >     exports table contains the name of every function that the DLL exports
> >     to other executables. These functions are the entry points into the
> >     DLL; only the functions in the exports table can be accessed by other
> >     executables. Any other functions in the DLL are private to the DLL.
> >     The exports table of a DLL can be viewed by using the DUMPBIN tool
> >     with the /EXPORTS option.
>
> You can export functions from a DLL using two methods:
>
> Create a module definition (.def) file and use the .def file when
>   building the DLL. Use this approach if you want to export functions
>   from your DLL by ordinal rather than by name.
>
> Use the keyword __declspec(dllexport) in the function's definition.
>
> When exporting functions with either method, make sure to use the
>   __stdcall calling convention.

Use the provided link to learn more about exporting from your dll's.

I think you got down voted because your point is not really clear, at least not to me. Also check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900axts6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It explains how to choose the export method.

Comment: +1 thanks for the info; however, your presumption that `You do not convert a dll to a DEF file` isn't always true. I sometimes do that (and I've seen others who also do so), sometimes because the LIB file isn't available for the DLL. You could argue that you shouldn't use the DLL in the first place, but sometimes that's what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Mehrdad, this isn't always a question of how to LINK to a DLL, as I, personally have NEVER linked a DLL using a .DEF file.  What I *HAVE* done is take someone else's DLL, and very painstakingly constructed a header file, or rather, function prototypes that I could use with 
`LoadLibrary()` in C, `Declare Function ... Lib "Foo.dll" Alias "OrdinalName"` in VB, and 
`[DllImport()]` in C#.

Of course, this is RARELY done, as if you are using a DLL for something, normally you have permission to do so, and the authors provide the .lib's, and the headers to go with the binary DLL file.

I've never done the exact techniques you speak of, by converting a .DEF info a .LIB, etc...  But, I suppose it would be easy to take a lib, or the DLL itself and export .DEF from it.  Now, THAT I actually *HAVE* done, in a project where the DLL code was built with a vbScript that took code from the main project, and created an API out of all the existing, compiled, and tested code.  This level of complication was only done because I had no idea what functions were going to BE in the DLL, as the main project could change at any time, so a static .DEF file would have never worked. So, I had to build the DLL once, capture the `dimpbin /exports`, undecorate the functions, and then build the .DEF file, and re-link the DLL.

If you find yourself in that type of situation, perhaps you need to re-think your original designs, and fix the problem from there...

As for .LIB files, USUALLY you'd only *NEED* those for static linkage, but they are also used when the .H file is available, often making debugging a just a little nicer...